# If zero then this must say invalid divisor but no idea how to do this

Tags: java, swing, applet

I need to change my Applet so if Zero it must say invalid divisor.

As mentioned I am very new to this and I just cannot seem to figure it out:

```
package JVA_Assessment_2;

import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Q1 extends Applet implements ActionListener{
      TextField text1,text2,output;
      Label label1,label2,label3;
      Button button;
      public void init(){
        setLayout(null);
        label1 = new Label("Enter Number1: ");
        label1.setBounds(20,20,100,20);
        add(label1);

        text1 = new TextField(5);
        text1.setBounds(150,20,100,20);
        add(text1);

        label2 = new Label("Enter Number2: ");
        label2.setBounds(20,50,100,20);
        add(label2);

        text2 = new TextField(5);
        text2.setBounds(150,50,100,20);
        add(text2);

        label3 = new Label("Sum of Two Numbers: ");
        label3.setBounds(20,80,130,20);
        add(label3);

        output = new TextField(5);
        output.setBounds(150,80,100,20);
        add(output);

        button = new Button("Sum");
        button.setBounds(150,110,100,20);
        add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
        int sum=num1/num2;
        output.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how I might fix this?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: A) java != javascript - so dont use tags that do not make sense B) talking about not making sense: studying **applets**. This is **dead** technology. Learn how to use Swing JFrames or JavaFX application. But forget about applets. Waste of time!

Answer (score 1):

Before you do your division you just check the number like this and print the error if necessary.

```
if (num2 == 0){
    output.setText("invalid divisor");
}
else {
    int sum=num1/num2;
    output.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess num2 is the variable you are talking about, try this:

```
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
    if (num2 == 0) {
        output.setText("Invalid divisor");
    } else {
        int sum=num1/num2;
        output.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }
```

read more about if statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
    if (num2 == 0) {
        output.setText("Cannot divide by zero");
    } else {
        int sum=num1/num2;
        output.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you divide num2, you should check if it is not equal to zero.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

    int num1=Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
    If (num2 == 0)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid divisor");
    }
    else
    {
    int sum=num1/num2;
    output.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }

    }
```

Comment: It throws `java.lang.ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main reason of inappropriate behaviour is in absence of exception handler. In other words you application throws an exception in background and it is not handled somehow.

application tries to divide on zero it throws `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` (type of `RuntimeException`). What you can do is adding a try-catch block which will display that something went wrong.

I created a quick example based on swing instead of applets which you can try to use for your needs:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static final String CALCULATE_BUTTON = "Calculate";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField operandOneField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField operandTwoField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField resultField = new JTextField(5);
        JLabel exceptionTracker = new JLabel();

        JButton button = new JButton(CALCULATE_BUTTON);
        button.addActionListener(s -> {
            exceptionTracker.setText(null);
            resultField.setText(null);

            String operandOneValue = operandOneField.getText();
            String operandTwoValue = operandTwoField.getText();
            try {
                int result = Integer.parseInt(operandOneValue) / Integer.parseInt(operandTwoValue);
                resultField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                exceptionTracker.setText(ex.getMessage());
            }
        });

        panel.add(operandOneField);
        panel.add(operandTwoField);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(resultField);
        panel.add(exceptionTracker);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Pay attention on lambda for `addActionListener` methods. The main magic happens there.

> This example works with java 8, so if you use previous version replace
>   lambda with anonymous class.
>
> ```
> button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>          ...
>     }
> });
> ```

In result of execution you will get a frame with three fields and one button. Once you will try do something wrong you will get error message under these controls, otherwise in the third text field you will get a result.

Hope this will help. Good luck.